# Index was outside the bounds of the array while using Lucene.NET

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.net version 3 library to index the data and search on them but for some reason, sometimes it throws a weird error message internally and I can not even understand why this happens. Below is my code when I try to search on the index:

```
using (var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30))
{
    using (var reader = IndexReader.Open(directory, true))
    {
        using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader))
        {
            term = QueryParser.Escape(term);
            var parsedQuery =
                new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, includedFields, analyzer)
                    .Parse(term);

            var result = searcher.Search(parsedQuery, reader.MaxDoc); //Here happens the error

            totalCount = result.TotalHits;

            var matches = result.ScoreDocs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).ToPaginated(page, size);

            foreach (var match in matches)
            {
                int docId = match.Doc;

                var document = searcher.Doc(docId);

                var item = //...

                list.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This error message does not always happen, it only happens when some random text string are being set as a searching term, so sometimes it works well and sometimes crashes.

I am trying to escape the term but still no luck. Does anybody have any idea what I might be doing wrong in here ?

Here is the error message:

> at Lucene.Net.Search.TermScorer.Score() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\TermScorer.cs:line 136 at Lucene.Net.Search.DisjunctionSumScorer.AdvanceAfterCurrent() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\DisjunctionSumScorer.cs:line 187 at Lucene.Net.Search.DisjunctionSumScorer.NextDoc() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\DisjunctionSumScorer.cs:line 155 at Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanScorer2.NextDoc() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\BooleanScorer2.cs:line 397 at Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanScorer.NextDoc() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\BooleanScorer.cs:line 369 at Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanScorer.Score(Collector collector) in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\BooleanScorer.cs:line 389 at Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher.Search(Weight weight, Filter filter, Collector collector) in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\IndexSearcher.cs:line 221 at Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher.Search(Weight weight, Filter filter, Int32 nDocs) in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\IndexSearcher.cs:line 188 at Blog.Services.SearchService.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0() in E:\Blog\Blog\Blog.Services\SearchService.cs:line 98 at

Here is a random string which makes it crash: **212 i think webapp using ef db first i am trying to use lazy**. The string does not have any meaning but still strange to me why it should make lucene crash...

Comment: @StephenBelden the error message is the title: Index was outside the bounds of the array. Thats all what I get from the exception object itself

Comment: this happens to me constantly too, nobody seems to have any answers as to why

Comment: For me this happened when I ran out of disk space part way through creating the index. This seems to suggest some kind of index corruption